# Easier way to loop through attribute array?

Tags: magento-1.9, template

Is there an easier way for me to code a template file to loop through certain product attributes using an array rather than specifying each attribute and testing for content?

As you can see from the code below I have several attributes names sequentially (setup_instructions1, setup_instructions2 etc...)

I'd much rather specify an array then have a simpler for each loop

Thanks

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Product Instructions') ?></h2>

    <div class=".grid12-1">

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_setups_tab')->toHtml() ?>

    </div>


    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
                <th class="label">Download Setup Instructions</th>

            <?php if($_product->hasSetupInstructions1()):?>
                <tr>
                <td class="spectabfile">
                <a href=
                <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/{$_product->getSetupInstructions1()}"; ?>
                <?php echo " target=\"_blank\">" ?>

                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?> </a></td></tr>
            <?php endif ; ?>

            <?php if($_product->hasSetupInstructions2()):?>
                <tr>
                <td class="spectabfile">
                <a href=
                <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/{$_product->getSetupInstructions2()}"; ?>
                <?php echo " target=\"_blank\">" ?>
                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions2')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></a></td></tr>
            <?php endif ; ?>


            <?php if($_product->hasSetupInstructions3()):?>
                <tr>
                <td class="spectabfile">
                <a href=
                <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/{$_product->getSetupInstructions3()}"; ?>
                <?php echo " target=\"_blank\">" ?>
                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions3')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></a></td></tr>
            <?php endif ; ?>


            <?php if($_product->hasSetupInstructions4()):?>
                <tr>
                <td class="spectabfile">
                <a href=
                <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/{$_product->getSetupInstructions4()}"; ?>
                <?php echo " target=\"_blank\">" ?>                 

                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions4')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></a></td></tr>
            <?php endif ; ?>


            <?php if($_product->hasSetupInstructions5()):?>
                <tr>
                <td class="spectabfile">
                <a href=
                <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/{$_product->getSetupInstructions5()}"; ?>
                <?php echo " target=\"_blank\">" ?>                 

                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions5')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></a></td></tr>
            <?php endif ; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
<?php 

    for ($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {

         $function_name="hasSetupInstructions".$i;

         if($_product->$function_name()):?>
            <tr>
            <td class="spectabfile">
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web',true). "pdf/".$_product->getData('setup_instructions'.$i); ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('setup_instructions'.$i)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?> </a></td></tr>
        <?php endif ; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: It works however I'm getting a fatal error:Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4194304 bytes)

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. You have the for statement checks reversed. Should have have been:  for ($i=1;$<6;$i++)